# Mouse position of JDialog relative to JTable

Tags: java, swing, position, jdialog

This is my code:

```
    JTable1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                          if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
                          {
                              JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
                              Point pMouse = new Point();
                              pMouse = target.getMousePosition();
                          }
                    }
               }
```

So I am retrieving the point (coordinates) relative to the JTable. So let's say the user clicks somewhere in a cell and the returned Point is X=272 and Y=50. So now I want to position a JDialog exactly by those coordinates. I tried:

```
jDialog1.setLocation(pMouse);
jDialog1.setVisible(true);
```

But this positions the Dialog somewhere else (the coordinates of the screen instead of the Table). Does somebody have a suggestion on how I can position the JDialog relative to the cell?

Comment: Follow standard Java naming conventions. Variable names do not start with an upper case character. That is JDialog1, should be `jDialog1` (well actually it should be a more descriptive name, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 3):

You are using the co-ordinates in relation to the client area of the `JTable` content. You want the global co-ordinates in relation to the entire window. For this you can use:

```
Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
jDialog1.setLocation(location);
```

Comment: I don't want to set it to the location of the mouse, but the location related to the cell itself

Comment: But when you click on the cell the mouse co-ordinates will be those of the cell. The co-ordinates used need to be globally based for positioning the dialog. The result will show the dialog positioned relative to the cell

Answer (score 0):

In general, a user should be able to use your application either by mouse or keyboard. What happens if the user tabs to that cell? Should they not be able to see the same dialog? So for a more general solution that works whether you use a mouse or not:

```
SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(point, table);
```

Check out the other convertXXX methods in SwingUtilities for future reference.

Or, you can always use:

```
Component.getLocationOnScreen();
```

and then add on the mouse point.